# NUnit tests all failed in Visual Studio Code (MacOS)

Tags: unity-game-engine, nunit, visual-studio-code, macos-sierra

I just started using VSCode (MacOS) and no matter the assertion, it always failed but it's not throwing any errors or warning to indicate that I set it up wrong. I have the following test unit:

```
using NUnit.Framework;

public class SampleTests
{
    [Test]
    public void SimpleAssertion() {
        Assert.That(true);
    }
}
```

Console output:

> Running test SampleTests.SimpleFail...
>
> Test failed

How do I run NUnit inside VSCode properly?

Comment: `SimpleFail` is (as its name suggests) failing.  The code you've posted is for `SimpleAssertion`

Comment: Thanks @Draco18s I just realized that I forgot to comment out old tests, I'm having issues with VSCode .net dependencies now so I can't run the tests but I think you pointed out the obvious haha thanks

Comment: Can you run the tests from the command line using `nunit3-console`? I normally use `TestFixture` on the class with `Test` on the methods. [TestFixture-Attribute[]https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestFixture-Attribute]